# How to use libjpeg to read a JPEG from a std::istream?

Tags: c++, iostream, istream, libjpeg

libjpeg can read JPEG data from a `FILE*` or a buffer. My data is coming from a `std::istream`. I could read the entire `std::istream` into a buffer to use with libjpeg, but I'd rather have libjpeg read directly from the `std::istream` if possible. How can this be done?

Comment: It's a C library... how could it possibly use an `std::istream`?

Comment: @Marlon: Bridging can be done if the library has the right hooks. E.g., [libpng can](http://www.piko3d.com/tutorials/libpng-tutorial-loading-png-files-from-streams).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You just need to provide wrappers around your istream. Define a struct, for instance

```
struct JpegStream {
  jpeg_source_mgr pub;
  std::istream* stream;
  byte buffer [4096];
}
```

Then you need four methods to operate on the stream:

```
void init_source (j_decompress_ptr cinfo)
{
    auto src = (JpegStream*)(cinfo->src);
    src->stream-> // seek to 0 here
}

boolean fill_buffer (j_decompress_ptr cinfo)
{
    // Read to buffer
    JpegStream* src = // as above
    src->pub.next_input_byte = src->buffer;
    src->pub.bytes_in_buffer = // How many yo could read

    return eof() ? FALSE : TRUE;
}

void skip (j_decompress_ptr cinfo, long count)
{
   // Seek by count bytes forward
   // Make sure you know how much you have cached and subtract that
   // set bytes_in_buffer and next_input_byte
}

void term (j_decompress_ptr cinfo)
{
    // Close the stream, can be nop
}
```

and one method to bind them to the JPEG decompression info structure:

```
void make_stream (j_decompress_ptr cinfo, std::istream* in)
{
    JpegStream * src;

    /* The source object and input buffer are made permanent so that a series
    * of JPEG images can be read from the same file by calling jpeg_stdio_src
    * only before the first one.  (If we discarded the buffer at the end of
    * one image, we'd likely lose the start of the next one.)
    * This makes it unsafe to use this manager and a different source
    * manager serially with the same JPEG object.  Caveat programmer.
    */
    if (cinfo->src == NULL)
    {   
            /* first time for this JPEG object? */
            cinfo->src = (struct jpeg_source_mgr *)
        (*cinfo->mem->alloc_small) ((j_common_ptr) cinfo, POOL_PERMANENT,   sizeof(JpegStream));
            src = reinterpret_cast<JpegStream*> (cinfo->src);
    }

    src = reinterpret_cast<JpegStream*> (cinfo->src);
    src->pub.init_source = init_source;
    src->pub.fill_input_buffer = fill_buffer;
    src->pub.skip_input_data = skip;
    src->pub.resync_to_restart = jpeg_resync_to_restart; /* use default method */
    src->pub.term_source = term;
    src->stream = in;
    src->pub.bytes_in_buffer = 0; /* forces fill_input_buffer on first read */
    src->pub.next_input_byte = NULL; /* until buffer loaded */
}
```

After calling `jpeg_create_decompress`, call your `make_stream` function.

Comment: Is `fill_buffer` supposed to return a `bool`? It's declared `void` but returns a value.

Comment: POOL_PERMANENT is JPOOL_PERMANENT in newer libjpeg

Comment: Here is a useful example for reading from memory buffer (not stream, but still very helpful): http://www.cs.stanford.edu/~acoates/decompressJpegFromMemory.txt

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on Anteru's excellent answer (from almost 13 years ago!), I produced the following code based on it. It wraps everything up together by using static member functions in the JpegStream struct and fully implements all the functionality (although I have not yet seen `skip` get called, so I am not 100% sure that works properly).

```cpp
#define STREAM_BUFFER_SIZE 4096

struct JpegStream {
    jpeg_source_mgr mgr;
    std::istream* stream;
    unsigned char buf[STREAM_BUFFER_SIZE];
    size_t ofs;
    static void initSource(j_decompress_ptr cinfo)
    {
        JpegStream* src = reinterpret_cast<JpegStream*>(cinfo->src);
        src->stream->seekg(0);
        src->ofs = 0;
    }

    static boolean fillBuffer(j_decompress_ptr cinfo)
    {
        // Read to buffer
        JpegStream* src = reinterpret_cast<JpegStream*>(cinfo->src);
        std::istream& stream = *src->stream;
        stream.read((char*)src->buf, STREAM_BUFFER_SIZE);
        src->mgr.next_input_byte = src->buf;
        src->ofs = 0;
        src->mgr.bytes_in_buffer = stream.gcount();
        return stream ? TRUE : FALSE;
    }

    static void skip(j_decompress_ptr cinfo, long count)
    {
        // Seek by count bytes forward
        JpegStream* src = reinterpret_cast<JpegStream*>(cinfo->src);
        if (src->ofs + count < STREAM_BUFFER_SIZE)
        {
            src->ofs += count;
            // Make sure you know how much you have cached and subtract that
            // set bytes_in_buffer and next_input_byte
            src->mgr.next_input_byte = &src->buf[src->ofs];
            src->mgr.bytes_in_buffer = STREAM_BUFFER_SIZE - src->ofs;
        }
        else
        {
            std::istream& stream = *src->stream;
            stream.seekg(count - STREAM_BUFFER_SIZE);
            src->mgr.next_input_byte = NULL;
            src->mgr.bytes_in_buffer = 0;
        }
    }

    static void term(j_decompress_ptr /*cinfo*/)
    {
        // Close the stream, be we ignore.
    }
    
    static void attach(j_decompress_ptr cinfo, std::istream* stream)
    {
        /* The source object and input buffer are made permanent so that a series
         * of JPEG images can be read from the same file by calling jpeg_stdio_src
         * only before the first one.  (If we discarded the buffer at the end of
         * one image, we'd likely lose the start of the next one.)
         * This makes it unsafe to use this manager and a different source
         * manager serially with the same JPEG object.  Caveat programmer.
         */
        if (cinfo->src == NULL)
        {
            /* first time for this JPEG object? */
            cinfo->src = (struct jpeg_source_mgr *)
            (*cinfo->mem->alloc_small)((j_common_ptr) cinfo, JPOOL_PERMANENT, sizeof(JpegStream));
        }
        JpegStream* src = reinterpret_cast<JpegStream*>(cinfo->src);
        src->mgr.init_source = initSource;
        src->mgr.fill_input_buffer = fillBuffer;
        src->mgr.skip_input_data = skip;
        src->mgr.resync_to_restart = jpeg_resync_to_restart; /* use default method */
        src->mgr.term_source = term;
        src->stream = stream;
        src->ofs = 0;
        src->mgr.bytes_in_buffer = 0; /* forces fill_input_buffer on first read */
        src->mgr.next_input_byte = NULL; /* until buffer loaded */
    }
};
```

Using it is easy:

```cpp
    std::istream stream;
    struct jpeg_decompress_struct cinfo;
    // Set up cinfo and stream
    JpegStream::attach(&cinfo, &stream);
```